# Why can't I call my constructor method within my module?

Tags: javascript

I have a module called Mole:

```
var Mole = (function(){

  function mole(id){
    this.id = id;
  }

  var randomMole = function(){
    var moleIndex = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 8);
    var mole = moles[moleIndex];
    return mole.id;
  }

  var score = 0;

  var moles = [];

  var generateMoles = function(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
      var mole = new mole(i);
      moles.push(mole);
    }
  }

  return {

    init: function(){
      //var mole = mole;
      generateMoles();
    },

    randomMole: randomMole,

    score: function(){
      return score;
    },

    incrementScore: function(){
      score += 1;
    }
  }


})()
```

I am calling Mole.init() when the document is ready.

This calls the generateMoles method which uses the mole constructor at the top of the module.  Except when the mole constructor is called within my generateMoles function I get this error:

```
model.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: mole is not a constructor
```

Why isn't mole a constructor? I defined it as one at the top of the module.

I thought it might be because the mole method was not in the scope of generateMoles when it is called in the init() function, because the init function would create a new closure for generateMoles which would not include the mole constructor.  So I tried a work around of defining mole in init function, so it would be included in the closure given to generateMoles..But I still get the same error whether I do this or not.

So now I'm out of ideas why I can't call new mole()..Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: My module is called Mole and I made a constructor inside of it called mole (lowercase), by saying new mole() aren't I using the constructor function I defined inside the module??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` declarations get "hoisted to the top" (i.e. to the outermost scope still within the function [see "var hoisting"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting)). Thus your `generateMoles` is equivalent to:

```
var generateMoles = function(){
  var mole;
  for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
    mole = new mole(i);
    moles.push(mole);
  }
}
```

This of course breaks the `new mole(i)` expression, because `mole` no longer refers to the `mole` function, but to the `mole` variable within that function.

The straightforward solution to this would be to simply use a different name for the local variable, such as `m`:

```
var generateMoles = function(){
  for(var i = 1; i <= 8; i++){
    var m = new mole(i);
    moles.push(m);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so when I declared the mole variable it was being hoisted to the same scope as the mole constructor and overriding it?

Comment: @srlrs20020 No, it doesn't get hoisted to the same scope. It stays within the `generateMoles` function, but inside there it _does_ override `mole` in the sense that the `mole` identifier now resolves to the local variable instead of the function (and with that also makes the `mole` function inaccessible because you've got no way to refer to it). Outside of `generateMoles` though, nothing changes.